# React TypeScript 16.8 How to add a dependency to useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

In useEffect() I make some keys then try and call the function addKeysToState() that is not in the useEffect() block and it's causing an error.

I've tried adding 'addKeysToState' and addKeysToState() into the array at the end of useEffect() but with no avail.

The error I get is...

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'addKeysToState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

the code snippet...

```
const FeedbackForm: React.FC<props> = ({publicKey}) => {
  const [formState, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const genRandomKey = async () => {
      const tempPrivateKey = await ecc.randomKey();
      if (tempPrivateKey) {
        const tempPublicKey = await ecc.privateToPublic(tempPrivateKey);
        if (tempPublicKey) {
          addKeysToState(tempPrivateKey, tempPublicKey);
        }
      }
    };
    genRandomKey();
  }, []);

  const addKeysToState = (tempPrivateKey: string, tempPublicKey: string) => {
              setState({ 
            ...formState, 
            tempPrivateKey,
            tempPublicKey,
          })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting `addKeysToState` inside the hook? It looks like it's not a dependency, but rather an implementation detail.

Note that since `addKeysToState` uses the previous state, we should use the callback form instead, to avoid racing conditions.

```
const FeedbackForm: React.FC<props> = ({publicKey}) => {
  const [formState, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const addKeysToState = (tempPrivateKey: string, tempPublicKey: string) => setState((prevState) => ({ 
     ...prevState, 
     tempPrivateKey,
     tempPublicKey,
   ))
    const genRandomKey = async () => {
      const tempPrivateKey = await ecc.randomKey();
      if (tempPrivateKey) {
        const tempPublicKey = await ecc.privateToPublic(tempPrivateKey);
        if (tempPublicKey) {
          addKeysToState(tempPrivateKey, tempPublicKey);
        }
      }
    };
    genRandomKey();
  }, []);
```

Comment: react then complains `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setState(f => ...)' if you only need 'formState' in the 'setState' call`

Comment: Can you make sure you use the callback form? (I edited the answer a couple of seconds after submission :p)